# Proving the collapse of a many body system (Fetter and Walecka problem 1.2)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, many-body, second-quantization

I was trying to solve the problem 1.2 from *Quantum theory of many-body systems* by A. Fetter and J. D. Walecka. I succeeded in the first part, obtaining the suggested formulation for the expectation value of the Hamiltonian in the non-interacting ground state.

However, the problem asks to prove also that a system with a potential $V(|x_{1}-x_{2}|)<0 $ for every $|x_{1}-x_{2}|$ (attractive and central potential) would collapse and I can't manage to do it.  I wrote the  mean energy per particle in terms of the Seitz parameter, but I'm stuck at this point:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{E^{0}+E^{1}}{N}= \frac{3\hbar^{2}}{10ma_{0}}(\frac{9\pi}{4})^{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{1}{r_{s}^{2}} +\frac{3W(0)}{8\pi a_{0}^{3}r_{s}^{3}}-\frac{1}{2V}\sum_{k m k' m'}^{k_{F}} W(|k-k'|)
\end{equation*}

where $W(k)$ indicates the Fourier transform of the potential and $r_{s}$ is the Seitz parameter.

I can't figure out how to prove that the exchange term doesn't create a repulsion at short range and, therefore, a minimum, causing a collapse of the system.

I add, as suggested, the text of the problem, to enhance the comprehension of the question:

> *Given a homogeneous system of spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles interacting through a potential V:*
>
> (a) *show that the expectiation value of the hamiltonian in the noninteracting ground state is*
>
> \begin{multline*}
> E^{0}+E^{1}= 2\sum_{k}^{k_{F}} \frac{\hbar ^2 k^2}{2m} + \\ +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{km,k'm'}^{k_{F}}[<km,k'm'|V|km,k'm'>-<km,k'm'|V|k'm',km>]
> \end{multline*}
>
> *where m is the z-component if the spin.*
>
> (b) *Assume $V$ is central and spin indipendent.* *If $V(|x_{1}-x_{2}|)<0$ for all $|x_{1}-x_{2}|$ and $\int d^{3}x |V(x)|<\infty$, prove that the system will collapse. (Hint: start from $\frac{E^{0}+E{1}}{N}$ as function of denstity)*

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! If you want to have a greater chance of your question being answered, you should copy the text of the problem you’re trying to solve into the question itself: an answerer might be reasonably expected to know what the Seitz parameter is, but very few will bother to track down a particular exercise in a particular book. (The less people have to bother with boring stuff, the greater the chance they will :).)

Comment: Note that you can use `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` (as well as other AMS environments) and even `$$ ... $$` or `\[ ... \]` to typeset equations here. I’ve gone ahead and edited your question to use that. I wasn’t sure where the $2/3$ power was supposed to go, though, so I left it as is—you might want to insert a pair of brackets or move the power inside the fraction.

Comment: Thank you for all the advices , my questions' format will surely improve. I hope this is the first of many collaborations as physicists.

Comment: Thank you for all the help after I edited the post to insert the problem text.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.2 just asks you to re-do the derivation of the momentum space Hamiltonian of the electron gas. Part b asks you to consider an attractive potential rather than a repulsive one, and moreover a screened potential (this is the meaning of the all-space integral of potential's magnitude |V|). If you work your way to the perturbative expansion, you should find that the energy-density lacks the point-minimum that is shown in Fig. 3.2 (which you can easily plot by just forgetting about your struggle with Problem 1.2 and throwing Eq. (3.37) into your favorite plotting program), and thus the system will either collapse or expand (depending on the slope (remember, force=-grad(V)) of the resulting plot).

Comment: I think that "prove" in the problem request means that you should be able to obtain a mathematical evidence that the system will collapse. In my formula I used the all-space integral to guarantee that $W(0)$ is finite, but I was not able to prove that there is no minimum.